# What command launches the UEFI shell?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to set up a UEFI boot system, and I've gotten all sorts of wonderful things done, except I can't figure out how to launch the UEFI shell. efibootmgr didn't work for me, so I need to run a bcfg, and to do that I need to launch the UEFI shell. I have the file in the efi partition, but I don't know how to run it. Does anyone here know?

Comment: Have you used $ cd src/qmeu and then $ ./runit ?

Answer (score 3):

Some EFIs' user interfaces provide an option to launch an EFI shell, either built into the firmware or stored on the ESP, typically in the root directory as `shellx64.efi`. This is far from universal, though, and the details of what the option is called vary from one EFI to another.

The way to do this that works most universally is to prepare a USB flash drive with the shell binary stored as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`. The flash drive must use FAT, and you might need to set the partition type code as for an ESP (to EF00 in `gdisk` or set the "boot flag" in a libparted-based program). When you use the EFI's built-in boot manager to boot from the USB flash drive, the shell will launch.

Most boot managers provide some means to do the job, too. In GRUB, you'd create an entry for the shell just as you would for other boot loaders. (The GRUB configuration scripts should auto-detect the shell binary if it's in certain locations; or you can create an entry in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` to do the job.) rEFIt, rEFInd, and gummiboot will all auto-detect the shell and create an entry for it if it's stored in certain locations. IIRC, `shellx64.efi` in the root directory of the ESP works for all three of these boot managers.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the bios will have an option somewhere to run it, but you should also be able to use use the grub command line ( press c at the grub menu ) and the `chainloader` command to run it.

Comment: If you'd explain the full chainloader command in the context of starting the efi shell. Your comment would be much more helpful.